# Continuous and responsive Beacons detection on Android

Tags: android, beacon

In our project we need very fast (ideally under few seconds), reliable and continuous beacon detection, most importantly in the background. Right now we are using the AltBeacon library, BeaconManager is initiated with a context of a foreground service (code provided).

In the foreground it works perfectly on almost any device, the problem is with working in the background. Some devices in the background don't work after some time (for example, Huawei P9 2017, I know it is problem with the device). In general we need better reliability.

The biggest problem is that detection on Oreo in the background is slow - from seconds to long minutes until it will report a first beacon. I have read the entry on AltBeacon web about changes for Oreo, so i know there are limitations from the system.
So here is my question, is there any way to improve the detection responsiveness (ideally on all android versions)? Even at a price of a bigger battery consumption or some hacks? I've tried to at least get an exception from battery optimizations in the system, but the results are probably the same.

BeaconManager configuration in Background service:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(1500);
    beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(0);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1500);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(0);
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));
    beaconManager.bind(this);
    if (CommConstants.sdkIsAtLeastSDK(21)) {
        BluetoothMedic medic = BluetoothMedic.getInstance();
        medic.enablePowerCycleOnFailures(this);
        medic.enablePeriodicTests(this, BluetoothMedic.SCAN_TEST);
    }
    goForeground();
}
```

Starting of monitoring:

```
private static final Region REGION = new Region(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null, null, null);

protected void startBeaconMonitoring() {
    if (beaconManager.isBound(this)) {
        findingEnabled = true;
        beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(
                (collection, region) -> {
                    for (Beacon beacon : collection) {
                        // beacon processing
                    }
                });
        try {
            mLogger.debug("Started beacon monitoring");
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(REGION);
            beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(REGION);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class).error("Monitoring start exception", e);
        }
        regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, REGION);
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}
```

I've noticed there is a PR for the beacon service to be in the foreground in android-beacon-library, is it possible that this will improve reliability?

Comment: Does the function goForeground(); make your custom service a foreground service?

Comment: yes, it will call startForeground() with notification to display (and it really is shown in notifications bar). On SDK>=26 service is stared with startForegroundService(intent) so it should be foreground service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Problem**

By default, the library running on Android 8+ will use JobScheduler to schedule the scans when your app is in the background.  But because Android limits jobs in the JobScheduler to be every 15 minutes, calling `beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(0);` has no effect on Android 8.  The latest library version introduces a warning in LogCat about this : `Setting a short backgroundBetweenScanPeriod has no effect on Android 8+, which is limited to scanning every ~15 minutes`.  See here for more details on this restriction:

http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2017/08/07/beacon-detection-with-android-8

**Known Solution**

A foreground service on Android 8 will let a service run continually to scan for beacons just like Android 4.x-7.x.  Making the library's scanning service a foreground service is known to work.   This is natively supported by library version 2.15+.  See [here](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/foreground-service.html) for details.

**Possible Alternative**

If you have your own custom foreground service separate from the library's scanning service, you may be able to use this to keep your app running.   But you have to turn off the JobSceduler scanning with:

```
 beaconManager.setSceduledScanJobsEnabled(false);
```

Because the above defaults to true on Android 8+.  After making that change, a long-running Service will be used to schedule the scans at the rate you specify.

Will this work?  It is unclear, because the library's scanning service is still not a foreground service, and may be killed by the Android 8 after running for > 5 min in the background.  The fact that you have another service in your app that is a foreground service may or may not be enough for Android 8 to let the scanning service live.  You will have to try.

Comment: It was enough to call      beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false), it really did improve a lot on Oreo. 
I have Huawei P9 Lite which after some time stops searching (similar to https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/554 ), have you some list of necessary hacks for various devices?

Comment: There are literally thousands of Android devices out there and new ones each day, so a list would be impossible to maintain without enormous resources.  For the Huawei devices, I would try running a foreground service with the background scan period set to max long. You simply cannot cycle scans with the screen off on Huawei devices, nor can you keep an app running without a foreground service.